# Integrating a date picker with database in VB

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, datepicker

I am trying to implement a date picker in my VB website. I am also using a database using LINQ. I have the following code to call the date picker.

```
<td>Start Date:</td>
<td>    
  <div>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
</td>
```

The table in the database has the following fields:

- ProjectID (int)
- ProjectName (vchar)
- Description (vchar)
- StartDate (datetime)

Any advice on how I can put in the datepicker and link it into the `StartDate` field in my database. Sorry if this is unclear. I'm just starting out. All suggestions welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have here 3 possibilities. The simpliest is to bind it somewhere where you get data from datasource and just assigning SelectedDate property of calendar control to data from datasource:

```
Dim tomorrow As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(1)
Calendar1.TodaysDate = tomorrow
Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate
```

The second one is based on using DayRender event and you can find a good explanation about this method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The last one was described in [Dino Esposito's article](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/bind-data-to-your-calendar) for DevPro and can be used for the case when you need such control in many pages. So, he explain how to create a reusable user control with standard properties like DataSource, DataSourceID and DataBind method.

Comment: Hi Apros, thank's for replying.  I read the articles provided and think dayrender is unsuitable. It seems to be for reading dates already stored in a database.  My need is to use the calender to write dates to the 'StartDate' field in my 'Projects' database table.  I have the calender in, I also have a textbox and a linkbutton with the calender.

Comment: When I run the website in browser I can click on the linkbutton, which then brings up the calender.  I can obviously select dates on the calender but my issue is that, once selected, I need the date to be submitted to the database.  I checked Dino's article. It's written for C# and I'm programming in VB.  Sorry to seem as though I am shrugging off all you have suggested.  As I said, I am new to this so your suggestions may be totally suitable and I am just not experienced enough to know how to implement them.  I'm desperate to get this working if possible so again your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I understand your question, but it's quite difficult to make an advice to you. Just because I don't know which technology you use for dealing with database (DataReader, DataTable, SqlDataSource, EF or other ORM). So, I cannot now provide you a best answer. But anyway you can use Calendar1.SelectedDate value to update your database with selected date. By the way if you have a trouble with c# to vb.net conversion you can use free tool from Telerik: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Hi Apros.  Thanks again.  I am using Visual Studio 2010.  I have created my database in VS2010.  I am setting my connections via LinqDataSource.  Thanks for the hyperlink and advice